# Anchored divs with nested anchors

Tags: css, html, anchor

On my site, I've got two large (100% x 100%) divs vertically stacked on a single page. Each of those divs has several sections inside it, each with an anchor. I have two floating sidebars on the left (only one is visible at a time) with links appropriate to each of the anchors. The first sidebar has the links for DivOne, and the second sidebar has links for DivTwo. There is also a link in each sidebar that 'swaps' the sidebars and divs. The sidebar looks like:

```
<div id="SidebarOne">
    <a href="#DivTwo">second screen</a>
    <a href="#OneSectionOne">Section One</a>
    <a href="#OneSectionTwo">Section Two</a>
    <a href="#OneSectionThree">Section Three</a>
</div>
```

I've reduced the CSS and HTML to the basics that I think are relevant. Here's the CSS:

```
#DivOne {
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    }

#DivTwo {
    top:100%;
    left:0%;
    }

#DivOne, #DivTwo {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    }

#Container {
    left: 50px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    }
```

And the HTML:

```
<a id="DivOne"><div id="DivOne"></a>
  <div id="Container">
    <a id="OneSectionOne">Title One</a>
         <p>Content</p>
    <a id="OneSectionTwo">Title Two</a>
         <p>Content</p>
    <a id="OneSectionThree">Title Three</a>
         <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>

<a id="DivTwo"><div id="DivTwo"></a>
  <div id="Container">
    <a id="TwoSectionOne">Title One</a>
         <p>Content</p>
    <a id="TwoSectionTwo">Title Two</a>
         <p>Content</p>
    <a id="TwoSectionThree">Title Three</a>
         <p>Content</p>
  <div>
</div>
```

Each of the divs is 100% x 100%, with DivTwo positioned at top:100%;

The problem I'm having is that when I click the links in the sidebar, it moves the whole page up so that the anchor is at the top of the page. I'm wanting it to only scroll the "container" div to the appropriate position, not the whole page. It seems to work on the bottom div (DivTwo), but I'm pretty sure that's just because it's sitting at the bottom of the page, and it can't physically scroll any further. I've tried giving the divs a 'position: fixed;' but that loses the ability to swap. I considered horizontally aligning the divs as well, but couldn't work it out nicely.

[Here is a demo of what I've got where you can see the problem. As you click links in the first section, the whole container moves up, revealing the section with the lighter background.](http://jsfiddle.net/jd4kt/)

So, how can I make only the 'container' div scroll and not the whole page?

Thanks in advance!

-----------EDIT-------------

I found the answer:

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/J2yTs/1/)

Basically, I just needed to move the second div across, so now it's at left:100%;

```
#DivOne {
top: 0%;
left: 100%;
}
```

Because they both rest on the bottom of the screen, there's nothing for it to scroll and reveal. A bit of a rough fix, but it seems to have worked!

Thanks to everyone who helped, though!

Comment: can you up some live code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jd4kt/ - There's a simplified version. Basically, in the first section (with the darker background), as you click a link, the whole screen slides up, revealing the lighter second container. That's what I'm hoping to remove. Without Javascript, if possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with anchors alone, but you can do it with JavaScript using the `scrollIntoView()` method. Here is a JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gBd25/

In this example, only the bottom div gets scrolled when the links are clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing

```
#DivOne {
  top:0%;
  left:0%;
 }
```

to

```
#DivOne {
  top:100%;
  left:0%;
 }
```